# Anybody is aware of a XML to SWI-Prolog binding tool similar to JAXB for Java or XSDE for C++?

Tags: xsd, jaxb, swi-prolog, xml-binding

Is it possible to create Prolog-specific bindings of XML schema files?  If so, can anybody point me in the right direction?

I have a schema which I use in Java to create a JAXB binding to serialize and de-serialize XML files.  These files are created by an SWI-Prolog application which is still evolving and is developed by a geographically distant team.  I want to make sure that when XML format changes, they are tied to a schema file change and not just view a schema as a nice documentation tool which often lags their actual XML content.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the general consensus is to use Prolog's JPL package to wrap a JAXB binding in Java.  This is the closest one seems to get to an actual binding implementation.

There is an SGML package which is used by many, but this is not a binding. As far as I understand, the best one can hope for is to be able to validate one's XML against the schema, but a quick look at the SGML documentation did not give me an impression that this functionality is actually fully implemented.

So, if one needs a schema binding-style XML management framework, the recommendation is to access JAXB binding of this schema via JPL.  Some folks expressed stability concerns of JPL.  They reported frequent crashes of JVM when using JPL, but I have not independently verified these claims and thus cannot confirm them. If anybody has more input on this topic, I would love to get it.

Thanks